# GGPlot2: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (16): x, y, group

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

Here is the code I have for what I thought was a simple line graph

```
ggplot(data=top15andAllDatasummary.df, aes(x=years, y=calculations, group=1)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

And I got this error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (16): x, y, group

I have data in a dataframe in r. My X-Axis was going to be years and the Y-axis was going to be some calculations (16 of them) I constructed per year.

Edited to add

```
structure(list(`2001` = c(349.315750645518, 217.47436370343, 
5.17963850977499, 126.661748432313, 57, 39), `2002` = c(703.26693877551, 
429.92, 9.32897959183673, 264.017959183673, 161, 108), `2003` = c(314.897774687065, 
193.792420027816, 4.08936022253129, 117.015994436718, 54, 37), 
    `2004` = c(305.988451086957, 190.680027173913, 3.87839673913043, 
    111.430027173913, 55, 38), `2005` = c(118.528015659408, 74.3175923660387, 
    1.50942011255199, 42.7010031808172, 10, 8), `2006` = c(120.531992244304, 
    73.8279205041202, 1.54362578768783, 45.1604459524964, 10, 
    8), `2007` = c(113.973899988451, 69.7619817530893, 1.44693382607691, 
    42.7649844092851, 10, 8), `2008` = c(110.676242590059, 67.3693570451436, 
    1.36285909712722, 41.9440264477884, 9, 7), `2009` = c(101.965558714192, 
    63.1446534003936, 1.22982724688388, 37.5910780669145, 9, 
    7), `2010` = c(93.9744360902256, 59.8894736842105, 1.14199785177229, 
    32.9429645542427, 9, 7), `2011` = c(91.8911316298046, 58.5660296328108, 
    1.15675327464033, 32.1683487223534, 9, 7), `2012` = c(91.2302181013592, 
    58.598356337583, 1.16773785691708, 31.4641239068591, 8, 6
    ), `2013` = c(87.1390443392165, 55.0509040034438, 1.10277658200603, 
    30.9853637537667, 8, 6), `2014` = c(85.7812132234942, 56.0456831068792, 
    1.09725045469134, 28.6382796619236, 8, 6), `2015` = c(88.331452900479, 
    58.526237360298, 1.22362959020756, 28.5815859499734, 8, 6
    )), .Names = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", 
"2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015"), row.names = c("AllDataMeanByYear", "AllDataMeanAggAssault", 
"AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter", "AllDataMeanRobbery", "AllDataMedianByYear", 
"AllDataMedianAggAssault"), class = "data.frame")


All Code:

 ## Total
lwdata$total <- lwdata$murdermanslaughter + lwdata$Robbery +    lwdata$Aggravated_assault
## Data Calculations Top 15
top15 <- lwdata[lwdata$total >= lwdata$total[order(lwdata$Year, lwdata$total, decreasing=TRUE)][15] , ]
## Top 15 Means
Top15MeanByYear <- tapply(top15$total,top15$Year,mean)
Top15MeanAggAssault <- tapply(top15$Aggravated_assault,top15$Year,mean)
Top15MeanMurderManSlaughter <- tapply(top15$murdermanslaughter,top15$Year,mean)
Top15MeanRob <- tapply(top15$Robbery,top15$Year,mean)
## All Data Means
AllDataMeanByYear <- tapply(lwdata$total,lwdata$Year,mean)
AllDataMeanAggAssault <- tapply(lwdata$Aggravated_assault,lwdata$Year,mean)
AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter <- tapply(lwdata$murdermanslaughter,lwdata$Year,mean)
AllDataMeanRobbery <- tapply(lwdata$Robbery,lwdata$Year,mean)
## Top 15 Medians
Top15MedianByYear <- tapply(top15$total,top15$Year,median)
Top15MedianAggAssault <- tapply(top15$Aggravated_assault,top15$Year,median)
Top15MedianMurderManSlaughter <- tapply(top15$murdermanslaughter,top15$Year,median)
Top15MedianRob <- tapply(top15$Robbery,top15$Year,median)
## All Data Medians
AllDataMedianByYear <- tapply(lwdata$total,lwdata$Year,median)
AllDataMedianAggAssault <- tapply(lwdata$Aggravated_assault,lwdata$Year,median)
AllDataMedianMurderManSlaughter <-  tapply(lwdata$murdermanslaughter,lwdata$Year,median)
AllDataMedianRobbery <- tapply(lwdata$Robbery,lwdata$Year,median)
## Rounding Data To Two Decimal Points
Top15MeanByYear <- round(Top15MeanByYear,digits=2)
Top15MeanAggAssault <- round(Top15MeanAggAssault,digits=2)
Top15MeanMurderManSlaughter <- round(Top15MeanMurderManSlaughter,digits=2)
Top15MeanRob <- round(Top15MeanRob,digits=2)
AllDataMeanByYear <- round(AllDataMeanByYear,digits=2)
AllDataMeanAggAssault <- round(AllDataMeanAggAssault,digits=2)
AllDataMeanAggAssault <- round(AllDataMeanAggAssault,digits=2)
AllDataMeanRobbery <- round(AllDataMeanRobbery,digits=2)
Top15MedianByYear <- round(Top15MedianByYear,digits=2)
Top15MedianAggAssault <- round(Top15MedianAggAssault,digits=2)
Top15MedianMurderManSlaughter <- round(Top15MedianMurderManSlaughter,digits=2)
Top15MedianRob <- round(Top15MedianRob,digits=2)
AllDataMedianByYear <- round(AllDataMedianByYear,digits=2)
AllDataMedianAggAssault <- round(AllDataMedianAggAssault,digits=2)
AllDataMedianMurderManSlaughter <-     round(AllDataMedianMurderManSlaughter,digits=2)
AllDataMedianRobbery <- round(AllDataMedianRobbery,digits=2)
## Summaries
AllDataSummary <- rbind(AllDataMeanByYear, AllDataMeanAggAssault, AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter, AllDataMeanRobbery, AllDataMedianByYear, AllDataMedianAggAssault, AllDataMedianMurderManSlaughter, AllDataMedianRobbery)
Top15Summary <- rbind(Top15MeanByYear, Top15MeanAggAssault, Top15MeanMurderManSlaughter, Top15MeanRob,Top15MedianByYear,Top15MedianAggAssault,Top15MedianMurderManSlaughter,Top15MedianRob)
Top15andAllDatasummary <- rbind(AllDataSummary,Top15Summary)
## Class of New Items
class(AllDataSummary)
class(Top15Summary)
class(top15andAllDatasummary)
## Converting Matrices to Data Frames
AllDataSummary.df <- as.data.frame(AllDataSummary)
Top15Summary.df <- as.data.frame(Top15Summary)
Top15andAllDatasummary.df <- as.data.frame(Top15andAllDatasummary)
## Checking of New Classes
class(AllDataSummary.df)
class(Top15Summary.df)
class(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
## Verifications for Names of New Components
colnames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
rownames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
## New Components
years <- colnames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
calculations <- colnames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
## Chicago
Chicago <- top15[which(top15$City=="Chicago"), ] 
## Basic Plots
plot(y=Chicago$total, x=Chicago$Year, type="l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Total       Violent Crime (minus rape)", main="Chicago-Specific Data", col="blue")
## Data Types for Chicago
str(Chicago)
```

link to full >100K set of data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8c2h1k2aartpf8/lwdata.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Would help to have data. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm really new to R and I have to say I'm struggling with trying to get you this data even after looking at that site. I don't want to get kicked off because of this

Comment: Please, try again. You won't get kicked off, but it is very difficult to help you without the data. Read about the function `dput` (in the link provided by @snoram). If you still find this hard, you can upload your data in a CSV file somewhere we can download it from. In the meantime, at least call `head(yourdata)` and show us the output so we have at least some idea. Also, connect ggplot layers by a single `+` and not two.

Comment: So your `data.frame` is `top15andAllDatasummary.df`.Could you do `dput(top15andAllDatasummary.df)` or `dput(head(top15andAllDatasummary.df))` and paste the results in your question as code?

Comment: I ran your code and it is giving me `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'years' not found`. This is logical, since *there is no variable called `years` in your data.* Please repeat the procedure with `dput` but this time provide the data on which you actually call the plot.

Comment: That's odd...because I ran this:
> ## New Components
years <- colnames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
calculations <- colnames(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)

Comment: Is this at all helpful? 
> str(Top15andAllDatasummary.df)
'data.frame': 16 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ 2001: num  349.32 217.47 5.18 126.66 57 ...
 $ 2002: num  703.27 429.92 9.33 264.02 161 ...
 $ 2003: num  314.9 193.79 4.09 117.02 54 ...
 $ 2004: num  305.99 190.68 3.88 111.43 55 ...
 $ 2005: num  118.53 74.32 1.51 42.7 10 ...
 $ 2006: num  120.53 73.83 1.54 45.16 10 ...
 $ 2007: num  113.97 69.76 1.45 42.76 10 ...
 $ 2008: num  110.68 67.37 1.36 41.94 9 ...
 $ 2009: num  101.97 63.14 1.23 37.59 9 ...
(There were rows for 2010-15 but I ran out of space

Comment: One problem I can see is this: In that ggplot call, you need to specify the variable for `x`. This needs to be the same length as your data - meaning the number of rows (16) - which it isn't, because the variable `years` has a different length (15). Also, please include *all the code* you have used directly in the question (so that we know what you have tried so far.) If you want years to be on the x axis, you need to restructure your data.

Comment: i've added all of my code and really hope it's not too overwhelming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data frame (let's call it `df`) has a column for each year, and rownames for each of your calculated variables. This is "wide" data, in which the same data type is stored across multiple columns. *ggplot* is meant to work with "long" data, in which each column contains a unique aspect of the data (i.e., separate columns for the variable, year, and data value).

The *tidyverse* library of packages, by Hadley Wickham (who also wrote *ggplot*), makes it easy to transform data from wide to long and back again. As of *tidyr* 1.0, this is accomplished via the `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` functions (previously `spread` and `gather`, respectively). I show both methods below.

```
library(tidyverse)

# current pivot_longer() implementation:
df.new <- mutate(df, variable = rownames(df)) %>%
    pivot_longer(-variable, names_to = 'year', values_to = 'value')

# deprecated gather() function
df.new <- mutate(df, variable = rownames(df)) %>% 
    gather(year, value, -variable)

                        variable year      value
1              AllDataMeanByYear 2001 349.315751
2          AllDataMeanAggAssault 2001 217.474364
3  AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter 2001   5.179639
4             AllDataMeanRobbery 2001 126.661748
5            AllDataMedianByYear 2001  57.000000
6        AllDataMedianAggAssault 2001  39.000000
7              AllDataMeanByYear 2002 703.266939
8          AllDataMeanAggAssault 2002 429.920000
9  AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter 2002   9.328980
10            AllDataMeanRobbery 2002 264.017959
11           AllDataMedianByYear 2002 161.000000
12       AllDataMedianAggAssault 2002 108.000000
13             AllDataMeanByYear 2003 314.897775
14         AllDataMeanAggAssault 2003 193.792420
15 AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter 2003   4.089360
16            AllDataMeanRobbery 2003 117.015994
17           AllDataMedianByYear 2003  54.000000
18       AllDataMedianAggAssault 2003  37.000000
19             AllDataMeanByYear 2004 305.988451
20         AllDataMeanAggAssault 2004 190.680027
... and 70 more rows
```

This long data can then be sent to *ggplot*. Note that your original attempt used a variable called "years", which did not exist in the data frame. R (and *ggplot*) have no way of knowing that your column names (2001:2015) somehow magically represent years.

```
plot.years <- ggplot(data = df.new, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
    geom_line()
print(plot.years)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on your data, I would do this:

```
library(tidyr)
top15andAllDatasummary.df$variable = rownames(top15andAllDatasummary.df)
df.long = gather(data = top15andAllDatasummary.df, 
                 key = years, 
                 value = calculations, 
                 -variable)
```

The point of this `gather` call is to restructure your data into this form:

```
head(df.long)
#                        variable years calculations
# 1             AllDataMeanByYear  2001   349.315751
# 2         AllDataMeanAggAssault  2001   217.474364
# 3 AllDataMeanMurderManSlaughter  2001     5.179639
# 4            AllDataMeanRobbery  2001   126.661748
# 5           AllDataMedianByYear  2001    57.000000
# 6       AllDataMedianAggAssault  2001    39.000000
```

Having done that, we can proceed to plotting:

```
ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = years, 
                           y = calculations, 
                           group=variable, 
                           color=variable)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point()
```

Is this your desired result?

Comment: Oh my goodness, jakub, thank you so much! off to look into ways to give you credit or help scores or points... I may want to edit things but i'm hoping i have it from here!

Comment: @laura It would be useful for others if you "accept" the answer (by clicking the check mark). In case of further questions regarding this particular piece of code, ask in the comments.

Comment: How would you subset AllDataMeanByYear? This didn't work: subset(AllDataSummary.df.new, subset=variable=“AllDataMeanByYear”) -> AllDataMeanByYea.Graph
Error: unexpected '=' in "subset(AllDataSummary.df.new, subset=variable="

Comment: Try reading the help page for `subset` - you can invoke the help page by calling `?subset` in R. Look at the examples, they should give you a hint.

Comment: I tried that before the question i posted and i still got that error:
> subset(df.long, variable==AllDataMeanByYear)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  dims [product 15] do not match the length of object [240]

Comment: First, I think you are missing quotes around `"AllDataMeanByYear"`.

Comment: Thank you... one last question promise. If I wanted to add another variable to this? subset(df.long, variable==AllDataMeanByYear)

Comment: If you want to satisfy multiple conditions (i.e. one variable equals x AND another variable equals y) try `subset(df.long, variable == "AllDataMeanByYear" & AnotherVariable == "somevalue")`. You can read more about logical operatos (such as `&` or `|`) on [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html). It also has a [chapter on subsetting, including the subset function](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html).

Comment: @laura as an addition to my previous comment, you can select multiple rows ("observations") from a single variable using the `%in%` operator (as in `variable %in% c("value1", "value2")`.

Comment: can someone please look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042472/r-tibble-vs-ggplot2-plotting-graphs  thanks